# Stopping a pthread which is in sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I have a thread (This is a Pthread in C implementation) which reads a value from a file every 5 secs. During shutdown, this causes an issue where the shutdown process wants to delete the thread but since it's sleeping, it has to wait for 5 secs for the sleep
to be done and then delete. How can I stop the thread even if it's in sleep as soon as I get the shutdown signal?

I already have a condition variable where the thread sleeps only if the condition is true (i.e - thread is running).

Scenario - As soon as the thread entered sleep, the shutdown signal is received; we have no way to proceed but to wait for the sleep to be completed.
Let's say

```
if (isThreadRunning == true) 
{
    sleep(5)
}
```

As soon as the shutdown signal is received the condition variable is made to be false. But even in this case, there is a chance that the signal might come just after 1st second we need to wait for 4 more seconds

The use of condition variable …

Comment: Instead of sleep, could use a `poll()` on (If using linux) an eventfd or (otherwise) a pipe with a 5 second timeout, and then write to the other end of that when you want the thread to shut down.

Comment: Have you investigated [`pthread_cancel()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html)?  It seems like you want to cancel the sleeping thread, and the sleep function is cancellation point.  See the POSIX specification for [Threads](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) and §2.9.5 Thread Cancellation.

Comment: First off, do you need to explcitly delete the thread at all?  On non-trivial OS, it's usually a pointless exercise.

Comment: I cannot use poll() as the existing thread functionality must be altered.
 I have tried using pthread_cancel (by setting state = enable and type asynchronous) - leads to crash/hang of program.

Yes, i need to explicitly delete the thread as this is very vital for quicker shutdown (lets say in case of embedded systems) The 5 secs of sleep is too much to wait for.

Comment: I don't think you understood Martin's point.  As long as the thread in question is not daemonized, it should not prevent the process (including that thread) from terminating when the initial call to `main()` returns.  And whether daemonized or not, it should not prevent the process from terminating when the `exit()` function is called in any thread.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop the thread even if it's in sleep as soon as I get the shutdown signal?

There are a few ways to handle this.

1. Does this thread actually *need* be joined?
   If not, simply call `exit` in the main thread, and this thread will disappear into the void.
   The problem with this approach is that there might be some necessary cleanups which this thread must perform.
2. Instead of calling `sleep(5)`, use [pthread_cond_timedwait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html), with the condition of "thread should continue running".
   When the `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns, check the condition. If true, read the number from the file and go back to `pthread_cond_timedwait`. If false, return from the thread function.
   The main thread should signal the condition and then join the thread.
   Note that spurious wakeups are possible, and so you should also check whether 5s have passed since the last time you've read the file.
3. Instead of `sleep(5)`, use `usleep(1000)`. When `usleep` returns, first check whether you should keep running, and if so, whether 5s have elapsed since last time your read the file.
   This solution is a kind of "busy wait" -- the thread will wake up much more than necessary.
   But it's simple and bounds the longest delay on shutdown to 1ms.